# handle when user closes or saves a file after Diagnostics.Process.Start vb.net/c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a Windows app that opens a file with Diagnostics.Process.Start(path), after opening the file user can modify it and I need to save it to db using a WCF. Is it possible to detect from the app that started the process when the file has been saved or closed by the user?
Thank you for your help

Comment: What type of file is it?

Comment: If you need to ask then probably not.  Lots of single-instance apps around.  When you start them again they can see that an instance is already running and ask that instance to open the file instead.  Big programs like browsers and Office apps work like that.

Comment: They are openoffice text and spreadsheet files (.odt and .ods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add an exit event listener to the process, and then do whatever processing that's needed after the user has exited the program. Here's a bare-bones example of the concept:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Public Event pEnd As EventHandler

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        p.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub p_Ended(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles p.Exited
        DoYourPostExitFileProcessing()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you talking about closing the file but leaving the program running?

Comment: Thanks, it is entering now, I put the line p.enableRaisingEvents = True after p.Start and it succesfully fires when user closes the file.  Is there any way to know when the user saves the file?

Comment: I am not aware of any direct way to have the process raise a "Saved" event, but there are two workarounds you could try. One is by using [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to raise an event when/if the file is modified. The other is to take note of the file's "Date Modified" date/time using [File.GetLastWriteTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime.aspx) before you start your process, then once the process ends check again to see if the Date Modified has changed.